# .NET Core Runtime only on Linux

Tags: security, .net-core, rhel

I'm trying to figure out a deployment strategy for our RHEL server with .NET Core microservices.

I was hoping that we could use a .NET Core runtime on our production systems rather than an "SDK" version.  The idea being that the runtime has less of an attack surface than perhaps the SDK would.

When I investigate the two options it seems I am downloading the exact same package:

```
yum install rh-dotnet22 -y
```

Why does Microsoft even bother making the distinction here?  Is there something I'm unaware of?  Is there a way to get runtimes only as opposed to SDKs?

Comment: Bit of a tangent, but if you are looking for "microservices", you probably want to use containers? And there are Red Hat-supported containers available: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/2.2/html/getting_started_guide/gs_install_dotnet#run_applications_on_linux_containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install rh-dotnet22-dotnet-runtime-2.2
```

This should do what you want. I will try and work with Microsoft to get the docs updated and I will ask our RHEL 7 docs to be updated too.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try this now :-)

Comment: Thanks again for this info!  You saved me and the team alot of time.  WOW.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction is what you say, if you just want to run applications you can install just the runtime.

If you want to build applications, you can install the SDK, which also includes the runtime.

On the website it does indeed look like both refer to the same package:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/sdk-current
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/runtime-current

Either they messed up the instructions, or they just offer the one.

Looking at the `Dockerfile` for a RHEL dotnet runtime container you can see the steps required to install the runtime only:

https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/blob/f344b26d956638600302b115fcc6693682f592b2/2.2/runtime/Dockerfile.rhel7#L51

The package for the runtime only looks to be `rh-dotnet22-dotnet-runtime-2.2`, but I'm not familiar with RHEL so I can't tell you whether that's all you need.

EDIT:
Updated link with input from [Omair Majid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3561275/omair-majid)

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  When I look at that example Dockerfile it seems its pulling from a CentOS image.  When reviewing the instructions from Red Hat side of things it recommends microservices based off of their rhel base image...  I'm going to keep digging around and see what else I learn...  To be clear:  We are using bare-metal services at this point, and not containers but ya the concept should definitely apply...  Maybe I can find more info from their Dockerfile (if there is one)

Comment: Just add a `.rhel7` suffix to the dockerfile link: https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/blob/f344b26d956638600302b115fcc6693682f592b2/2.2/runtime/Dockerfile.rhel7#L51 to see the version based on RHEL container images.